# Why does "with" exist in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I can't understand why "with" is needed in this sentence.

Are you through with your lunch?

I think that This sentence means 
"Did you have your lunch? "
And in second sentence, there is no "with". So I think that there is no need to exist the word "with" in first sentence.

"Through" means went completely and finish something, doesn't right? 
"With" means "by", doesn't right? 
So that, I feel first sentence mean "did you have by your lunch?"

I'm confused by "with".

Please teach me, why the word with is exist in the sentence.

Comment: Note: asked earlier at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205094 , but I think this version does address the suggestions for improvement made on the earlier post.

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to EL&U. You might be interested in our sister site, English Language Learners; you can find it [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). It is helpful in answering basic questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of 'Are you through with your lunch?' is closer to 'Have you finished your lunch?' than 'Did you have your lunch?'

The idiomatic expression 'be through' in this sense is intransitive; it cannot be followed by a direct object. We need a preposition, and the preposition happens to be *with*. Don't fall into the trap of thinking that, just because two words or phrases have very similar meanings, they must function in the same grammatical way.

Comment: Thanks for your explaining very easily to understand. I've understood.